# Suppressing iPhone's native video player when playing HTML5 video

Tags: iphone, video, mediaplayer

on iPhone, when you have an HTML5 video tag on a web site and you click play it will open the iPhone's native video player and play the video there (unlike on the iPad where it will play the video in the on-site HTML5 video player).

Is there a way of suppressing the native player and play the video in the browser in the on-site HTML5 video player on iPhone?

Thanks

Comment: "the on-site HTML5 video player" on the iPad is actually the same player as the one on the iPhone, the iPhone one is just modified to take advantage of the smaller screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a way to do this, currently. The size of the video and the movie controls would be far too small if it didn't zoom to full-screen.